# Mu4e not autofilling email addresses

Tags: mu4e

I seem to have a problem with mu4e not correctly autofilling email addresses. According to [this page](http://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu4e/Address-autocompletion.html), this should happen automatically. And for many (most?) addresses it does. But then others it doesn't get for whatever reason.

Any ideas where to start here?

Comment: This sounds more like a bug report than a question.  Please consider creating an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/djcb/mu

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
(setq mu4e-compose-complete-only-personal nil)
```

Also, make sure you always launch mu4e with `M-x mu4e`.